# Bomb Lab Phase 6 :Stuck on the last step

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

This is asm code for phase_6

```
    08048de3 <phase_6>:
 8048de3:   56                      push   %esi
 8048de4:   53                      push   %ebx
 8048de5:   83 ec 4c                sub    $0x4c,%esp
 8048de8:   65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
 8048dee:   89 44 24 44             mov    %eax,0x44(%esp)
 8048df2:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8048df4:   8d 44 24 14             lea    0x14(%esp),%eax
 8048df8:   50                      push   %eax
 8048df9:   ff 74 24 5c             pushl  0x5c(%esp)
 8048dfd:   e8 42 03 00 00          call   8049144 <read_six_numbers>
 8048e02:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8048e05:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
 8048e0a:   8b 44 b4 0c             mov    0xc(%esp,%esi,4),%eax
 8048e0e:   83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
 8048e11:   83 f8 05                cmp    $0x5,%eax
 8048e14:   76 05                   jbe    8048e1b <phase_6+0x38>
 8048e16:   e8 04 03 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048e1b:   83 c6 01                add    $0x1,%esi
 8048e1e:   83 fe 06                cmp    $0x6,%esi
 8048e21:   74 1b                   je     8048e3e <phase_6+0x5b>
 8048e23:   89 f3                   mov    %esi,%ebx
 8048e25:   8b 44 9c 0c             mov    0xc(%esp,%ebx,4),%eax
 8048e29:   39 44 b4 08             cmp    %eax,0x8(%esp,%esi,4)
 8048e2d:   75 05                   jne    8048e34 <phase_6+0x51>
 8048e2f:   e8 eb 02 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048e34:   83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
 8048e37:   83 fb 05                cmp    $0x5,%ebx
 8048e3a:   7e e9                   jle    8048e25 <phase_6+0x42>
 8048e3c:   eb cc                   jmp    8048e0a <phase_6+0x27>
 8048e3e:   8d 44 24 0c             lea    0xc(%esp),%eax
 8048e42:   8d 5c 24 24             lea    0x24(%esp),%ebx
 8048e46:   b9 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%ecx
 8048e4b:   89 ca                   mov    %ecx,%edx
 8048e4d:   2b 10                   sub    (%eax),%edx
 8048e4f:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
 8048e51:   83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 8048e54:   39 c3                   cmp    %eax,%ebx
 8048e56:   75 f3                   jne    8048e4b <phase_6+0x68>
 8048e58:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
 8048e5d:   eb 16                   jmp    8048e75 <phase_6+0x92>
 8048e5f:   8b 52 08                mov    0x8(%edx),%edx
 8048e62:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 8048e65:   39 c8                   cmp    %ecx,%eax
 8048e67:   75 f6                   jne    8048e5f <phase_6+0x7c>
 8048e69:   89 54 b4 24             mov    %edx,0x24(%esp,%esi,4)
 8048e6d:   83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
 8048e70:   83 fb 06                cmp    $0x6,%ebx
 8048e73:   74 17                   je     8048e8c <phase_6+0xa9>
 8048e75:   89 de                   mov    %ebx,%esi
 8048e77:   8b 4c 9c 0c             mov    0xc(%esp,%ebx,4),%ecx
 8048e7b:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 8048e80:   ba 3c c1 04 08          mov    $0x804c13c,%edx
 8048e85:   83 f9 01                cmp    $0x1,%ecx
 8048e88:   7f d5                   jg     8048e5f <phase_6+0x7c>
 8048e8a:   eb dd                   jmp    8048e69 <phase_6+0x86>
 8048e8c:   8b 5c 24 24             mov    0x24(%esp),%ebx
 8048e90:   8d 44 24 24             lea    0x24(%esp),%eax
 8048e94:   8d 74 24 38             lea    0x38(%esp),%esi
 8048e98:   89 d9                   mov    %ebx,%ecx
 8048e9a:   8b 50 04                mov    0x4(%eax),%edx
 8048e9d:   89 51 08                mov    %edx,0x8(%ecx)
 8048ea0:   83 c0 04                add    $0x4,%eax
 8048ea3:   89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
 8048ea5:   39 c6                   cmp    %eax,%esi
 8048ea7:   75 f1                   jne    8048e9a <phase_6+0xb7>
 8048ea9:   c7 42 08 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x8(%edx)
 8048eb0:   be 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%esi
 8048eb5:   8b 43 08                mov    0x8(%ebx),%eax
 8048eb8:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
 8048eba:   39 03                   cmp    %eax,(%ebx)
 8048ebc:   7d 05                   jge    8048ec3 <phase_6+0xe0>
 8048ebe:   e8 5c 02 00 00          call   804911f <explode_bomb>
 8048ec3:   8b 5b 08                mov    0x8(%ebx),%ebx
 8048ec6:   83 ee 01                sub    $0x1,%esi
 8048ec9:   75 ea                   jne    8048eb5 <phase_6+0xd2>
 8048ecb:   8b 44 24 3c             mov    0x3c(%esp),%eax
 8048ecf:   65 33 05 14 00 00 00    xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
 8048ed6:   74 05                   je     8048edd <phase_6+0xfa>
 8048ed8:   e8 b3 f8 ff ff          call   8048790 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 8048edd:   83 c4 44                add    $0x44,%esp
 8048ee0:   5b                      pop    %ebx
 8048ee1:   5e                      pop    %esi
 8048ee2:   c3                      ret
```

By analysing, i have to input 6 non identical digits and are less than 6 and should separated by space. So randomly entered 6 5 4 3 2 1 .
Values of nodes 1 to node 6 are as follows:

```
(gdb) x/3x $ebx
0x804c13c <node1>:  0x000003c8  0x00000001  0x0804c148
(gdb) x/3x *($ebx + 8)
0x804c148 <node2>:  0x0000018c  0x00000002  0x0804c154
(gdb) x/3x *(*($ebx + 8 )+ 8)
0x804c154 <node3>:  0x00000325  0x00000003  0x0804c160
(gdb) x/3x *(*(*($ebx+8)+8)+8)
0x804c160 <node4>:  0x0000012c  0x00000004  0x0804c16c
(gdb) x/3x *(*(*(*($ebx+8)+8)+8)+8)
0x804c16c <node5>:  0x0000008a  0x00000005  0x0804c178
(gdb) x/3x *(*(*(*(*($ebx+8)+8)+8)+8)+8)
0x804c178 <node6>:  0x00000219  0x00000006  0x00000000
```

From there, in ascending order, the input should `5 4 2 6 3 1`
but i get exploded, i even tried `1 3 6 2 4 5` but i kept getting exploded. Where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: This is almost a good question; nicely formatted, and you have an attempt and sensible methodology for using GDB to examine the linked-list nodes.  But what's missing is any explanation of what you found out in reverse-engineering the code.  You don't even mention the phrase "linked list".  I assume that's why someone (not me) downvoted.  (Most questions asking for help on bomb lab phases haven't shown any effort at all and just have the code dump, so you're doing better than most.  Hope this helps you write questions that get upvotes in the future.  And welcome to Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to see where i was wrong, on the line `8048e46:   b9 07 00 00 00          mov    $0x7,%ecx`   can be written as f(x)=7-x where x is an index.
So before, input was `1 3 6 2 4 5` which is  wrong, i had to apply the function.
The new input is `6 4 1 5 3 2` which defused the bomb